Can I recover my investment? I've been scammed
I am a victim of a scam. There is a company saying that they can recover what was stolen, it's almost 200 k euros and according to them, I am required to top up the balance of your secure crypto wallet by 3-5% of the requested amount and send them the confirmation of payment.
The email is refund@blockchain-department.net but I don't know if should trust them.
Can anybody say if they are legit or not?

Legitimate companies, especially those dealing with refunds or recovery of stolen funds, do not typically require an upfront payment. Asking for 3-5% of the requested amount to be topped up in a crypto wallet is a common tactic used by scammers. Do not send any money. Report the incident to your local authorities.

See also Is there a 'BTC Refund Department'? and Who really controls bitcoin

Översätt text med kameran
thanks for your answer. Until now I notice many inconsistencies in the emails... definitely scammers... I don't know what else to do to recover my losses

How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?
